# Check for previously submitted value in $_POST and replace default selected item

Tags: php, wordpress, post, dropdown

I'm struggling with making a dropdown list work in wordpress & PHP which includes a default option and then a list of different areas.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Initially set my default option as selected.
2. If the form has been submitted, add the selected attribute to the selected item and delete the selected attributed from the default option.
3. Reset the selected option to default when the page is being reloaded.

I have come up with the code below, but the only thing that is working so far is that the previously selected option is being kept after submit.

```
<select name="by_area">
    <option value="default" disabled="" <?php if (!isset($_POST['by_area'])) { echo "selected";} ?>>select option</option>
    <?php foreach($categories as $value) :?>
      <option
        value="<?php echo $value->slug; ?>" 
        <?php echo (isset($_POST['by_area']) && $_POST['by_area'] === $value->slug ) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $value->name; ?>
      </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The first `isset($_POST['by_area'])` should be `!isset($_POST['by_area'])` – you want your default option set as selected, if _no_ values was passed so far, right?

Comment: @04FS I did that but then after submitting, the default value is selected (and not the option that had been selected on submitting, which is what I want)

Comment: Did you actually change the _first_ one, on the default option? Not talking about the one later on the specific options.

Comment: @04FS Yes, I implemented your change.